# Passing properties object to jQuery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, parameters, jquery-animate

I have this piece of code:

```
var delta = _window.width() / 30, // resize hexagons by delta px
window_height = _window.height(); // .box-1/window height

 $('.hexagon').each(function () { // get animated boxes
    var $this = $(this),
        width_1 = $this.width(),
        height_1 = $this.height(),
        multi = 0, // adjust resize to scroll speed (depends on delta)
        ratio = 1.167; // to calculate height

    // animation properties
    var enlarge_obj = {
            width: function() {return width_1 += (delta * multi)},
            height: function() {return width_1 * ratio}
        },
        shrink_obj = {
            width: function() {return width_1 -= (delta * multi)},
            height: function() {return width_1 * ratio}
        };


        ....


        function scrollHandler() {
            ...
            $this.animate(enlarge_obj, 0, 'linear');
            ...
            $this.animate(shrink_obj, 0, 'linear');
        }
}
```

I want to pass enlarge_obj and shrink_obj to jQuery animate function.

But it doesn't work.

If I write code like this:

```
$this.animate({width: width_1 += (delta * multi), height: width_1 * ratio},0,'linear');
```

it works fine.
What am I doing wrong? Thx.

Comment: Are you calling your animate function from within the `$.each`? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, everything is in each loop. There is no errors in console.

Comment: jQuery doesn't animate functions, but numbers